# Rails 3, Eagerly Load Model

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, performance, eager-loading

I have a query that is is running lots of these at once,

```
print Account.where("id%100=0").where(:has_videos=>true).count
print Account.where("id%100=1").where(:has_videos=>true).count
print Account.where("id%100=2").where(:has_videos=>true).count
```

And i was wondering if there was a way to use eager_load or something along those lines to a point where this still works quickly, but requires only one pull.

Comment: Can't you just load them all in one query and then break that resultset as you like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Account.group('id % 100').count
```

This will return a hash where the keys are the residues modulo 100 and the values are the counts.

Comment: That is AWESOME. Can you explain how the group function works a bit more? Like other ways to use it?

Comment: Rails is just exposing the SQL group function. Good for aggregating data, eg number of orders but with separate totals for each customer